# how to get probability in classification problem

Tags: keras

I am learning ML with this tutorial. https://pythonprogramming.net/using-trained-model-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/
When I try to use the model to predict, I only get 0 or 1, but I thought that since the last layer is

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

the final output would be in the range [0,1] and not the extreme value 0 or 1. How can I get the exact result?

Comment: Instead of using model.predict() use model.predict_proba() to get the actual prediction value.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think it is true. model.predict_proba() is deprecated and gives the same thing as model.predict(). When I tried it I got the following warning:
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-6-89bb23cd8ab5>:1: Sequential.predict_proba (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential) is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `model.predict()` instead.

Comment: Maybe it is deprecated for the time but there is no suitable replacement for getting actual prediction value as model.predict() give hard value. Though deprecated, you can still use it to see the actual probability value.

Comment: I tried model.predict_proba() again on three images one dog, one cat and one random landscape, but still got only 0 and 1.

Comment: Its possible that the model or input data is just not setup or trained correctly, especially since a random landscape gives the same values as a true dog or cat image. To verify the model you created, model.summary() will show you the model layers. If that looks ok, then need to verify the input and test data next. FWIW, I also get a float value when using predict() or predict_proba(). Need to use predict_classes to get a binary 0/1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. I tried `model.summary()` and looked at the outputs of intermediate layers. My mistake was not normalizing the test input.